# What does the node health value in a Datastax node compose of?

Tags: cassandra

On a datastax Cluster (6.7.8) I can run:

`nodetool node_health --all`

This gives a list of values for the cluster with IP addresses and health values - eg

```
IP Address    Node Health
1.2.3.4       1.0
1.2.3.5       0.5
```

Where the list of health values are between 1 and 0.

But it's not clear what this is telling you, when it is less that 1.0. I want another command to drill down into this value and find out all the things that make it up.

My question is: **What does the node health value in a Datastax node compose of?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching for the phrase "What does the node health value in a Datastax node compose of?" brings back several links to Datastax documentation pages, which all say [basically the same thing](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.7/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/tools/dsetool/dsetoolNode_health.html):

> Node health is a score-based representation of how fit a node is to handle search queries. The node health composite score is based on dropped mutations and uptime. A higher score indicates better node health. Nodes that have a large number of dropped mutations and nodes that are just started have a lower health score.